# Machine Learning in wrist movements

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am trying to detect the motion of flicking your wrist using a 6-axis IMU.  So far the only good features I have found are the mean and standard deviation of the last 10 readings for each of the 6-axes.

Does anyone have any ideas for other features to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the derivatives. To get the velocity take the difference between adjacent points (and then average it those differences). To get the acceleration, take the difference between the velocities, etc.